# Error:Failed to find: com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0

Tags: android, android-studio

I am going to migrate to android studio.

I would like to use this lib :

https://codeload.github.com/flavienlaurent/datetimepicker/zip/master

after this tutorial :

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1MyBO9z7ojk

now I get this error :

> Error:Failed to find: com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0

---

build.gradle in **datetimepicker-library** :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionName rootProject.versionName
        versionCode rootProject.versionCode
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}

//apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push/master/gradle-mvn-push.gradle'
```

---

**updated**

[image]

all my error :

Comment: Is that all the error said? Can you include the entire error? Also, this library s deprecated.

Comment: What is the **error**? No internet? Can't find it locally? It is on `mavenCentral()`: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.nineoldandroids/library/2.4.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update this

```
    dependencies {
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0+'
}
```

Then **Gradle** your project

Answer (score 3):

it's simple actually, just past

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

to your **build.gradle** of the project (not the build.gradle of the module)